# Why do you allow users to access the "submit questions" page if they can't submit questions?

Tags: support, new-users

Why do you design your website so users can spend an hour typing out a question with a detailed description, just to find out they can't submit the question because they don't have 10 reputation yet?

Why don't you just not give people access to the "submit a question" page until they have the reputation? Is it really that complicated to do in Javascript?

Comment: You don't need 10 rep to ask questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts. Maybe you ran into new user restrictions? http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user

Comment: Your account has 35 rep and two questions already. What page are you on?

Comment: Are you talking about the question ban?

Comment: @Mysticial He's not question-banned.

Comment: Which site are you talking about? The only thing I can think of off the top of my head that'd prevent you from posting a question on any of the sites you registered on so far is if you tried to post on the Home Improvement Meta instead of the main site (since meta sites except this one require 5 reputation for posting questions & answers).

Comment: @AnnaLear He doesn't have an account on HI Meta.

Comment: @kiamlaluno SE 2.0 meta sites don't have separate accounts that show up in the account list.

Comment: @AnnaLear I know; that is why I checked on HI: He doesn't have a link to his meta account. `:)` I am still wondering why he is referring to 10 points, though.

Answer (score 9):

As I think more about this, let me make a couple guesses: did your question include more than two links or an image?

Both of those are a part of [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) that are lifted once you reach 10 reputation. The reason we don't prevent you from hitting the "Ask Question" page before you have 10 reputation is because you actually can ask questions at that point. We have no idea whether or not you're going to try including content you can't yet include.

If you want to include an image, just paste in a link to it and a higher-reputation user will edit your post to inline it. If you want to include more than two links... well, you're probably out of luck on that one, but if your question gets a couple upvotes, you'll quickly get the 10 reputation needed to get past these restrictions and you'll be able to add the links in yourself.

If none of this applies to your situation, you'll really need to give us a bit more information - such as the site you were on and what error message (if any) you got when trying to submit your question.

Comment: He could also be trying to edit a protected question. Not sure what the flow is for that, for users with <10 rep.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Yeah, there are a couple other possibilities. I wouldn't call them "submitting a question", but this whole report is kinda vague.